# how to add a UISearchBar in the middle of a NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Basically I have this app that has a Navigation Controller and 2 buttons in the Navigation Bar. 
Now my problem is that I want to put a search bar in the middle of the navigation bar in between the 2 buttons, Any thoughts? This is what i want to achieve:

[image: This is what i want to achieve]

Comment: Create a custom navigation bar with left button(as your screen shot), then search bar and right button(as in the screen shot)

Comment: You can use navigation titleview for that you can add search bar on title view